# bare bone csv-parse won't parse anything

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse

with the below code I expect to see records being printed.  But I get radio silence.  No error or any records being printed.

CSV file content and located in same folder as index.js

```
userId,prefChannel
1,push.pref
2,email.pref
3,email.pref
4,email.pref
5,push.pref
6,push.pref
7,email.pref
8,push.pref
9,email.pref
10,push.pref
```

csv version is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "csv": "^6.2.0"
  }
```

index.js code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { parse } = require('csv-parse');

async function readRecordsFromCSV() {
    const cvsFileName = (__dirname + SETTINGS.filePath);
    console.info(chalk.green(`Streaming file: ${cvsFileName}`));

    // read csv file
    const parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function(err, data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(err);
      });
      
      fs.createReadStream(cvsFileName).pipe(parser);
}

// driver code:
// Run the script
; (async function () {
    // read and transform all items from csv file
    const newPrefs_1 = await transformPreferenceRecordsFromCSV();
})()
```

I will start the script by passing in the file name and here is my test output:

```
**Streaming file: {correct file path}/.../bq-results-10-records-test.csv**
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in question actually works.  My local has this at the end of the driver code which caused it to terminate early.

```
process.exit(1);
```